# Curl command to save Rails send_data output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, libcurl, rails-api

I'm a new bee to the rails api and curl commands.

I have a rails api which response to request sends from the native app. And to one of the requests sent from native api using curl command my rails api is sending file saved to the database to that desktop app.

But I'm not getting how to save that file using curl commands when I use curl -o/-O commands only file object is saved (example: #) and not the actual file. When I call the same rails method on the browser I get the file downloaded properly.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
I can save those file types which can be displayed inline on the browser but not all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any shell command and save it into the file by `> file_name` command. In your case it will be

`curl http://example.com > filename`